# Post on facebook to unlock

Tags: php, facebook

I have some special features for the users which sends a post to their Facebook about my service, out there, there are lots of scripts which could detect "Like" and then we could unlock some features for users(Like to unlock), but I want that users POSTS a post and then unlock the feature, not just Like.

With my FB like button, after liking it, it automatically opens a small window so they could post something, How I could detect POSTS and not just Like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I want that users POSTS a post and then unlock the feature

That would be a violation of [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> IV. Application Integration Points,
>
> 1.) You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Comment: But why there is lots of scripts out there which could do such functions about Facebook "Like"? see this: http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-like-locker-for-jquery/2303230?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=TylerQuinn

Comment: What they consider a “social channel” is linked to a further explanation on this page, https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#Facebook_social_channels Using “like” to gate content behind is accepted by Facebook; using other channels – as you are planning to do, by gating content behind a _required post_ on one’s wall – __is not.__

Comment: But not impossible, right? since I asked a programmer which had worked with FB API, he said that's completely possible...

Comment: Of course it’s possible … but how much help do you expect here in developing something that violates FB’s terms?

Comment: Everything’s possible. It’s possibly for me to take a knife from the kitchen drawer and slit my girlfriend’s throat who’s sitting beside me. Doesn’t mean it’s right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); //start PHP session
session_regenerate_id(true); //Generated new session id
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tweet_content" class="locked_ct"><h5>Tweet to Unlock this Content</h5>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="saaraan">Tweet</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//All event bindings must be wrapped within callback function
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {

    //######## trigger when the user publishes his tweet
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {

        /*
        To make locked items little more private, let's send our base64 encoded session key
        which will work as key in send_resources.php to acquire locked items.
        */
        var data = {unlock_key : '<?php echo base64_encode(session_id());?>'};
        //Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.
        $.post("send_resources.php", data, function(data)
        {
            //Append unlocked content into div element
            $('#tweet_content').html(data);

        }).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //Output any errors from server.
            alert( thrownError);
        });
    });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>






<?php
session_start(); // session start

//retrive base64 encoded post variable and compare it with session id.
if (isset($_POST["unlock_key"]) && base64_decode($_POST["unlock_key"])===session_id())
{
    //user unlocked item by tweeting.
    echo "Congratulations! You just unlocked this text by Tweeting!";

}else{
    //Output HTTP errors
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Oops! something went wrong...');
    exit();
}
?>
```

THat's for twitter, but it probably can be adapted to facebook.

Comment: So you're not sure? If you're not sure that it can be adapted, then you shouldn't post it as an answer.